# Must all logical axioms be proven to be universally valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In first order logic, we select a set of sentences as the logical axioms. I would like to know if all the logical axioms are required to be proven to be  universally valid in meta language. Or, we can select a formula that cannot be proven to be  universally valid in meta language to be a logical axiom in a first order language? I raise this question because some logical axioms seem complicated to be proven.

Comment: Yes all logical axioms are valid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do we need to prove every of these logical axioms to be valid, or we can just assume some of them are valid?

Comment: There are many equivalent [proof systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122079/convincing-yourself-about-choice-of-axioms-for-predicate-calculus), each with his own axioms. For a specific proof system, we have to prove that ALL axioms are valid. Having said them, they are quite similar...

Comment: The proof is straightforward using def of truth in a model for formulas: $\mathcal M,s \vDash \varphi$. You have e.g. to apply the semantical clause for $\forall$ to $\forall x \varphi(x) \to \varphi [x/t]$.