# Enderton First Order "Forall" $\forall$ Axiom - Why is it needed?

Tags: first-order-logic

In Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" page 112 it gives as an axiom of First Order Logic :

$$ \forall x \; (\alpha (x) \implies \beta (x)) \implies ( \forall x \alpha (x) \implies \forall x \beta (x) ) \tag{1}$$

This is in addition to :

$$ \forall x \; \alpha(x) \implies \alpha^x _ t \tag{2}$$

with t substitutable for x in $\alpha$ and

$$ \alpha \implies \forall x \; \alpha(x) \tag{3}$$

where x is not free in $\alpha$.

My question is : Why is Axiom (1) above needed given axioms (2) and (3) ?

I ask this because it looks like Axiom (2) can be used to show, for any integer n :

$$ \forall x \; (\alpha (x) \implies \beta (x)) \implies ( \forall x \; \alpha (x) \implies \beta (t_1) \land \beta (t_2) ... \land \beta (t_n)   ) \tag{1a}$$

however deductions and expressions are finite in first order logic, so $\beta (t_1) \land \beta (t_2) ... \land \beta (t_n) $ can not be replaced by $\forall x \beta (x)$ using only Axiom (2). Axiom (3) can't be used either. So Enderton's Axiom (1) above is used to "plug this infinity gap" ?

Comment: There are many choices regarding the set of [axioms and rules for first order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122079/convincing-yourself-about-choice-of-axioms-for-predicate-calculus). Enderton's one is due to the author aim of using **only** Modus Ponens** as rule of inference. Thus, the above axioms are needed in order to prove the **Generalization Theorem** (see page 117).